# Error TestMethod do not support Web service callouts in TestDataFactory test method

Tags: apex

I have test class with two test methods. One creates the test data in TestDataFactory. This method is giving the error: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts.

The other method in this test class is a test method to do the mock callout which is passing. What could be the issue? The code is below. Thanks!

```
@isTest
private with sharing class TransactionBuildSendJson_Test {

    @isTest
    static void testCreateTestData(){

        // Test data setup
        // Create two transaction records with two transaction item records each
        // by calling the utility method
        Transaction__c[] trans = TestDataFactory.createTranWithTranItems(2,2);
        System.assertNotEquals(null, trans, 'Should create atleast one test transaction record');
    }

    @isTest
    static void testTransactionCallout() {  // Test sending transaction json
        // Set mock callout class
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TransactionHttpCalloutMock());
        // This causes a fake callout to be sent from the class
        // that implements HttpCalloutMock.

        // Call the method that sends the paylaod
        Test.startTest();
        TransactionBuildSendJson.sendPayload('testpayload');
        Test.stopTest();
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1) don't you want the method `testCreateTestData` to be annotated with `@TestSetup`? and 2) does that method end up calling code that does a callout?

Comment: No, @TestSetup is not needed as this common test data creation class can be used by all test classes and not just various test methods in a particular test class. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_data - also no, testCreateTestData doesnt do the called out, but the next test method testTransactionCallout does. This test class is for an after insert trigger though.

Comment: I'm confused. It will be executed as a testmethod when you execute the testclass. Why did you inlcude it in the post? Please clarify using [edit]

Comment: Does your `TestDataFactory` class doing any callout? Can you check in triggers or somehwere, where the data might get inserted and the trigger might be doing a callout in future or so, or there might be a `Page.PageName` getting called.

Comment: Yes in TestDataFactory test records are created in the parent and child object (like in the trailhead link above) and my trigger is an after insert on the child object.

Answer (score 2):

Your `TestDataFactory` class will only produce `TestMethod do not support Web service callouts in TestDataFactory test method` error message when one of the following are true:

1. TestDataFactory does a **callout**.
2. TestDataFactory inserts an object, whose trigger does **callout** in future.
3. TestDataFactory inserts an object, whose trigger runs and inserts another object, and that objects trigger might be doing a callout (again in future).

One of these conditions in my view is correct. Only then `TestDataFactory` can throw that error.

You need to check triggers and check debug debug logs (with Apex profiling ON) for `Number of future calls`, or callouts. That might give you an exact idea, where is the call being made.

And escape the call with `Test.isRunnningTest` or mock the call in your `isTest` method.